# Set focus on tab of property page on mfc

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2022, cmfcpropertypage

MFC: I like to set the focus on the tab of the property sheet. Using the tab key, I can reach the tab, but I did not find a way of doing this by calling a function. The problem is that the tab is not one of the controls in the page, and I do not know where to find the window handle for the tab.
My goal is to prevent any of the controls on the property page to receive the focus when I activate the property page. Same behavior as if I navigate to the page using the arrow keys instead of clicking on the tab.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: You prevent a window from receiving focus by setting the [`WS_DISABLED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) window style. If you subsequently need to move focus to another control, send a [`WM_NEXTDLGCTL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-nextdlgctl) message to the dialog and the dialog manager will figure things out for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found what seems to work:

In OnInitDialog I added:

for (i = 0, first = GetFocus(), win = NULL; (i < 20) && (win != first); i++)
{
 NextDlgCtrl();
 id = GetFocus()->GetDlgCtrlID();
 if (id >= 8192)
 {
  TabID = id;
  break;
 }
}

In OnSetActive I added:

PostMessage(WM_APP_SETPAGEFOCUS, 0, 0L);

And the I added the function:

LRESULT MyTab::OnSetPageFocus(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 CWnd* win;

 while(1)
 {
  win = GetFocus();
  if (win)
   if (win->GetDlgCtrlID() == TabID)
    break;
  NextDlgCtrl();
 }
 return 0;
}

Feels way too complicated...